# How to run a for-loop through a string vector of a data frame in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, panel

I'm trying to do something very simple: to run a loop through a vector of names and use those names in my code.

```
geo = c(rep("AT",3),rep("BE",3))
time = c(rep(c("1990Q1","1990Q2","1990Q3"),2))
value = c(1:6)
Data <- data.frame(geo,time,value)
```

My real dataset has 14 countries and 75 time periods. I would like to find a function which for example loops through the countries, then subsets them so I have the single datasets such as:

```
data_AT <- subset(Data, (Data$geo=="AT"))
data_BE <- subset(Data, (Data$geo=="BE"))
```

but with a loop and ideally with a solution I can apply to other functions as well :-)

In my mind, this should look something like this:

```
codes <- unique(Data$geo)
for (i in 1:length(codes))
{k <- codes[i]
data_(k) <- subset(Data, (Data$geo==k))}
```

however subset doesn't work like this, neither do other functions. I think my problem is that I don't know how to address the respective name which "k" has taken (e.g. "AT") as part of my code. If at all possible, I would very much appreciate an answer with a general solution of how I can run a function through a vector containing text and use each element of that vector in my code. Maybe in the direction of the apply functions? Though I'm not getting very far with that either...

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using loops for simiral purposes too. Maybe it's not the fastest way, but at least I understand it -- for example, when saving plots for different subsets.

There is no need to loop through length of vector, you can loop through vector itself. For converting string to variable name, you can use assign.

```
geo = c(rep("AT",3),rep("BE",3))
time = c(rep(c("1990Q1","1990Q2","1990Q3"),2))
value = c(1:6)
Data <- data.frame(geo,time,value)

codes <- sort(unique(Data$geo))
for (k in codes) {
 name<-paste("data", k, sep="_")
 assign(name, subset(Data, (Data$geo==k)))
}
```

BTW, filter from package dplyr is much faster than subset!

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm reading tutorials about the xapply functions to appease the R purists now but its still great to have code that works AND that I understand... :-D

Comment: Yeah, I'm learning apply too and try too use apply whenever possible (vapply is my favourite), but can't figure out how to use apply for purpose like this. No use to spend two days for optimizing something that works good enough.

Answer (score 2):

In R, you would typically do this with a `list` of data.frames instead of several separate data.frames:

```
lst <- split(Data, Data$geo)
lst
#$AT
#  geo   time value
#1  AT 1990Q1     1
#2  AT 1990Q2     2
#3  AT 1990Q3     3
#
#$BE
#  geo   time value
#4  BE 1990Q1     4
#5  BE 1990Q2     5
#6  BE 1990Q3     6
```

Now you can access each element (which is a data.frame) by typing:

```
lst[["AT"]]
#  geo   time value
#1  AT 1990Q1     1
#2  AT 1990Q2     2
#3  AT 1990Q3     3
```

If you have a vector of country names for which you want to add +1 to the value column, you can do it like this:

```
cntrs <- c("BE", "AT")
lst[cntrs] <- lapply(lst[cntrs], function(x) {x$value <- x$value + 1; return(x)} )
#$BE
#  geo   time value
#4  BE 1990Q1     5
#5  BE 1990Q2     6
#6  BE 1990Q3     7
#
#$AT
#  geo   time value
#1  AT 1990Q1     2
#2  AT 1990Q2     3
#3  AT 1990Q3     4
```

Edit: if you really want to stick with a for loop, I recommend not to split the data into several separate data.frames but to run the loop on the whole data set like this for example:

```
cntrs <- "BE"  

for(i in cntrs){
   Data$value[Data$geo == i] <- Data$value[Data$geo == i] + 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats a great solution for the subset case but doesn't help me with my general problem. Say I have more countries and want to add +1 to the value of a few of them. I would like to create a vector of those few and then run a loop though that vector and add +1 to the value of these countries. How would this syntax work?

Comment: Thanks a lot! But is there no way to loop this? I could imagine one hundred cases where I could use loops without having to learn and write different functions each time. For example to run lm() through the different subsamples and save the different models for stargazer or to save plots for different countries and so on and so forth... I am really looking for a loop! :-)

Comment: It would be possible in a loop, but that would actually be considered bad practice in R. If you're going to use R in the future, it's absolutely worthwhile learning the `*apply` family of functions, especially `apply`, `sapply` and `lapply`. If you really want to stick with a loop, I would at least recommend not splitting the data in many separate data.frames but keeping them in one and only subsetting in the loop. I'll post an example.

Comment: great, thanks! And thanks for the hint with the apply functions, I guess there is no way around it in the long run... :s